# PHP incrementing through data set

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, mysqli

```
    global $mysqli;
    $building = $position['buildingID'];     
    if($level == 'room') {

        // Get building size 
        $buildingQuery = "SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE buildingID = '$building'";
        $buildingArea = $mysqli->query($buildingQuery) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $Area = $buildingArea->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $AreaX = $Area['areaX'];
        $AreaY = $Area['areaY'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE buildingID = '$building'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $rooms = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        for($y = 0; $y <= $AreaY; $y++){
            for($x = 0; $x <= $AreaX; $x++) {
                //See if room exists for coordinates
                    if(($rooms['position_x'] == $x) && ($rooms['position_y'] == $y)
                        && ($position['room_x'] == $x) && ($position['room_y'] == $y)) {
                        echo '<img src="../../resources/images/inroom.php" id="'.$x.'_'.$y.'" />';
                        echo ' ';
                    } else if (($rooms['position_x'] == $x) && ($rooms['position_y'] == $y)) {
                            echo '<img src="../../resources/images/inroom.php" id="'.$x.'_'.$y.'" />';
                            echo ' ';
                    } else {
                        echo "(".$x.","." ".$y.")";
                        if ($x == $AreaX) {
                            echo '<br />'; 
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the issue is I have a grid system, I need to display the result set where coordinate X, and Y, align in the database, but I don't really get how to increment the rows I'm retrieving, any advice?

EDIT: Code update

Comment: I do know that currently it ends up being an infinite loop.

Comment: Why are you retrieving your room information inside the for loops? Is it likely to change? Why not do it outside the loops? Also you should review the while condition. If I understand your problem correctly there is an array of rooms and you need to find those rooms that have the same x and y position, right?

Comment: It's possible to change and each building has a different schematic, and you are correct, yeah the while loop is broken, but I'm not sure how/why.

Comment: To restate the issue, I need to pull to pull room info from the building table, the default state for a room is empty, so I just have two entries which are not empty, but the coordinates are different. I need to output "room", "blank" "blank", "room" where room is equal to the loops x, and y.

Comment: ^ Aye, I've got it removed for the moment on the dev server, it does run forever because I don't understand how to increment to the next result set.

Comment: I don't see x and y having an influence on your query. So why would the result change inside the loops?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I'm coming at it the wrong way then. ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I took your fetching of rooms and took it outside the loops. Then I generated a map of room coordinates. That way you only have to loop through the rooms once instead of doing it for each row and column of the grid.

Then to round it up I iterate over the grid and check if the coordinates are in the map. If they are we have found a room, otherwise we have found a blank.

```
$rooms = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$map = array();

foreach($rooms as $room)
{
    $position_x = $room['position_x'];
    $position_y = $room['position_y'];
    $map[$position_x][$position_y] = $room;
}

for($y=0;$y<=$AreaY;$y++)
{
    for($x = 0; $x <= $AreaX; $x++) 
    {
        if(isset($map[$x][$y]))
        {
            // room
        }
        else {
            // blank
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, sometimes you just need a fresh perspective. Thanks :D